# When a DST day has 82800 seconds, why half a day is 43600?

Tags: postgresql

I have next two queries to calculate a day and a half of day

```
tucha=> select extract( epoch from '2019-03-31'::timestamptz +interval '1day' - '2019-03-31'::timestamptz );
 date_part 
-----------
     82800
(1 row)

tucha=> select extract( epoch from '2019-03-31'::timestamptz +interval '0.5day' - '2019-03-31'::timestamptz );
 date_part 
-----------
     43200
(1 row)
```

if one day is 82800, then a half a day should be 41400, is not?

```
tucha=> select extract( epoch from '2019-04-01'::timestamptz -'2019-03-31'::timestamptz )/2;
 ?column? 
----------
    41400
(1 row)
```

**NOTICE** `postgresql` actually calculate `43200`, but I expect `41400` as it calculated for last expression

**NOTICE** both: `1day` and `0.5day` periods contain time when DST occur

**UPD**
Is there a spec about how half a day is calculated for days when DST occur?

Comment: Without using timestamptz: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=59d41240d45e86398884c6dce15fcde2

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `Europe/Zaporozhye`. Actually 23hours in my timezone

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: Yes, but I want take into account timezone

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes. And I do not understand why `postgresql` does not take into account timezone for a half of day. PG bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808527/when-a-day-has-82800-seconds-why-half-a-day-is-43600?noredirect=1#comment100171317_56808527). And [screenshot](http://i.piccy.info/i9/f420f68b7283545a45d8f34d2a1a2831/1561732751/34208/1316591/_.jpg). `select '2019-03-31'::timestamptz + interval '0.5day' - '2019-03-31'::timestamptz;` is `12:00:00`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: It stays on same day: `2019-03-31` and DST occur at `03:00`, so it **must** be affected. A half of day for `2019-03-31` is `11:30`, I think. Is there a spec about how half a day is calculated for this case?

Comment: Very interesting: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=acbe096126f19769aa650ac1cf0afc9e

Comment: @EugenKonkov: on a DST change day, if the hour is always added or subtracted at 0300 the first half of the day is either 11 or 13 hours long and the second half of the day is twelve hours long. There are other ways to implement this (when I was in the navy, westbound time zone changes were adjusted on the second dog watch (1800-2000, with the clock being set back an hour at 1900), and eastbound time zone changes were adjusted on the midwatch (0000-0400), with the clock being moved forward an hour at 0100). So "half a day" is not half the minutes in the day, and may not always be equal.

Comment: I believe it is a bug indeed. It's not calculated properly. There is a subtraction of an hour at +24(+x) hours. So +23,5 hours > +24hours. Although the DST (in my example) is at 1h -> 2h (an that is calculated correctly). So the DST is not recognized on a timerange < 1day. And that looks not correct.

Comment: @BobJarvis Good explanation. But nevertheless, (see my fiddle) the whole calculation seems to have a problem with 24+ hours

Comment: @S-Man: those calculations apply for month too. Try the half of month for months of 28, 29, 30 and 31 days. S-Man. I agree with you that these calculation should be clarified with examples